# At least one object must implement IComparable - working on Local Machine but not on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, icomparable

I know there are several other Post about this Exception but none of them helped me.

Each of the 3 Solutions is working on my local Machine but not in Live-System / On the Server.

As the number of PackageViewModels increased, the First Solution quitted work. - Implemented Second Solution. Users added two more Items and the Second Solution also quitted work - Implemented third, which never worked on Server. :D

EDIT: - Some more information... The functions GetTemplateTypes(), GetTemplateCategories() and GetPackages() are returning lists of Models which are queried via ADO.net raw SQL from SQL Server 2008. These functions are always returning the queried data and theres never any Kind of exception throwing.

```
public ActionResult Package_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var templateTypes = DBRepository.GetTemplateTypes();
            var templateCategories = DBRepository.GetTemplateCategories();
            var templatePackages = DBRepository.GetPackages();

// Third Solution, never worked

            List<PackageViewModel> packageViewModels = new List<PackageViewModel>();

            foreach (var templatePackage in templatePackages)
            {
                PackageViewModel packageViewModel = new PackageViewModel();
                packageViewModel.val1= templatePackage.val1;
                packageViewModel.val2= templatePackage.val2;
                packageViewModel.ID = templatePackage.ID;
                packageViewModel.Type =
                    (from t in templateTypes where t.ID == templatePackage.ID select t).First();
                packageViewModel.Category = (from t in templateCategories
                    where t.Category_ID == templatePackage.Category_ID
                    select t).First();
                packageViewModels.Add(packageViewModel);
            }


// Second Soltuion - Worked for an amount up to 14 packageViewModels

            var packageViewModels = templatePackages.Select(p => new PackageViewModel
            {
                VPackage_ID = p.VPackage_ID, 
                VType = (from t in templateTypes where t.ID == p.VType_ID select t).Single(), 
                VCategory = (from t in templateCategories 
                    where t.VCategory_ID == p.VCategory_ID select t).Single(), 
                val1 = p.val1, 
                val2 = p.val2
            }).ToList();




// First Solution - Worked till a specific number of PackageViewModels ( about 12)

            IEnumerable<PackageViewModel> packages = DBRepository.GetPackages()
                .Select(p => new PackageViewModel
                {
                    VPackage_ID = p.VPackage_ID,
                    VType = DBRepository.GetTemplateType(p.VType_ID),
                    VCategory = DBRepository.GetTemplateCategory(p.VCategory_ID),
                    val1 = p.val1,
                    val2 = p.val2,
                });


            var jsonResult = Json(packageViewModels.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Util.logger.Error(ex.Message);
            return new JsonResult();
        }
    }
```

I absolutely have no Idea how to handle this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: where is the error being thrown from? When you test locally are you using the same data source as when it fails? Could you post the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
ERROR 2016-09-12 16:09:28,695 890063ms Util                   Package_Read            
At least one object must implement IComparable
ERROR 2016-09-12 16:09:28,696 890064ms Util                   Package_Read          - mscorlib
ERROR 2016-09-12 16:09:28,697 890065ms Util                   Package_Read            
at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.CompareKeys(Int32 index1, Int32 index2)
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.CompareKeys(Int32 index1, Int32 index2)
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.QuickSort(Int32[] map, Int32 left, Int32 right)
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SkipIterator>d__30`1.MoveNext()
at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Execute[TModel,TResult](IQueryable source, Func`2 selector)
at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.CreateDataSourceResult[TModel,TResult](IQueryable queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState, Func`2 selector)
at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IQueryable queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IQueryable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request)
at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IEnumerable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request)
```

Error was thrown at

```
var jsonResult = Json(packageViewModels.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Found a Solution, changed the Sorting of the kendo UI Grid in the View. Still don't understand why different Solutions were working. Seems everything is working finde now.